# CSS issue with span

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate a logo with plain text and CSS no images, the issue I have I can't seem to get padding to 0 around the text so that top and bottom text are only 2-5px apart.

Also is it possible to have them one on top of the other but not the have BIG TITLE CSS to

> display:block

instead only to wrap around the text.

**jSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/theStudent/ag60a6hs/

**CSS:**

```
/* FONT IMPORT */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300,700);

.logo_large_txt{
  color: #2faed9;
  margin:0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 36px;
  background-color: #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
}

.logo_small_txt{
  color: #c2c2c2;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <span class="logo_large_txt">BIG TITLE</span>
    <span class="logo_small_txt">SMALL CAPS</span>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: As mensioned this is `line-height` issue. For one bellow another you need to add `<br />` tag between `span`'s. Modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag60a6hs/1/) are You looking for something like this?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I did line height but I must have done something wrong as I didn't get the same result. However I applied line-height on both elements and not on a div wrap that might have been the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a padding issue, it's a line-height issue. Set `line-height: 1em;` on the relevant elements (those with text in them) and see how the height of the element now equals the size of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding `line-height` might help, for example `line-height:50%` for logo_large_txt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is `line-height` issue. You could set `line-height` to 1 or less on div and see the result.

For second part You should add `<br />` tag between `<span>` tags.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag60a6hs/3/) or preview:

```css
/* FONT IMPORT */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300,700);

.logo_large_txt{
  color: #2faed9;
  margin:0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 36px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.logo_small_txt{
  color: #c2c2c2;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div.logo {
    line-height: 0.8;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
    <span class="logo_large_txt">BIG TITLE</span><br />
    <span class="logo_small_txt">SMALL CAPS</span>
</div>
```